# iPad volume isn't working

Tags: ipad, sound-volume

My nan's iPad volume isn't working. She asked me why and I'm not sure why it could be as the volume is turned up and she can hear her music but she goes on to Snapchat and she can't hear anything but when she uses her headset she can hear.

Comment: a reboot will sometimes fix these kind of issues.

Answer (score 2):

Can she change the volume with the buttons on the side?

If so, it should have to do with the other side button (which is set to either rotation lock or mute/unmute ringtone in the settings app) being set to mute/unmute ringtone and being switched to mute. Try flipping that button, it should fix it :).

If not, I have no idea or advice.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried to perform a power cycle?

To power cycle the iPad, hold the power switch down for 10 seconds until the power off slider appears on the front of the phone, you must continue to hold the top switch as you operate the power off slider. Wait a minute and turn the iPad back on with the switch.

If you are still experiencing problems, I would backup and reset the iPad to test it. Do the following:

- Plug your iPad on your computer.
- On iTunes → Your iPad → Sumary → Back Up Now.
- Once done, on your iPad go to Settings → General → Reset → Reset All Content And Settings.
- Test it.

If works, restore the previous backup on iTunes → Your iPad → Sumary → Restore Backup...

If does not work, perform a power cycle and test again.

If after the reset and power cycle, still does not work, is a hardware issue and you must take it to an Apple Store.

Answer (score 0):

I have an iPad 2 and my volume wasn't working. I couldn't figure it out until I thought of unplugging it from the charger. Possibly your iPad's volume isn't working because you have it plugged in to your charger.

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same problem all you have to do is unplug your iPad if it's plugged in

Answer (score -2):

Try restarting the iPad. That should fix most problems.

Answer (score -2):

Turn the device off and on again it should work or if that doesn't work take it into your nearest Apple Store they will be able to help

Comment: Sending the user to the Apple Store after rebooting isn't really the best answer possible here, I would suggest that after 8 months there is little chance they still need support, if they did however it would be best to use comments to probe the user through troubleshooting steps.